# Troubleshooting CORS Issue with Azure-hosted Node.js Server and React Frontend on Cloudflare

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, cors, cloudflare

I've developed a web application with a React frontend and a Node.js backend, and I'm encountering a CORS issue when deploying it. Here's the setup:

1. Node.js backend runs on an Azure Windows VM.
2. React frontend is hosted on Cloudflare.
3. A certificate is installed on the VM for HTTPS.

When I run the application locally, everything works fine. However, in the production environment, I receive a CORS error when the frontend attempts to fetch data from the backend. The error message is:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://azureIPRemoved:3000/api/articles?title=What%20is%20the%20question%20removed?. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

I also get an error labeled as "Error fetching articles", followed by a lengthy stack trace. The most relevant parts appear to be:

Network Error
AxiosError
ERR_NETWORK

I've implemented the cors middleware in my Express.js server as follows:

```
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

Despite this, I'm still seeing the CORS error. I have also ensured that all requests use HTTPS and have set various environment variables in Cloudflare to no avail.

I'm struggling to understand the root cause of this issue. Could anyone help me debug this or suggest potential solutions?

Comment: Perhaps you are hitting this one? https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html#enabling-cors-pre-flight